# Resnetv2 implementation in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet

I would like to understand a detail about Resnetv2 in Keras, the one in tensorflow.keras.applications.ResNet50V2. How come the first convolution layer has the same number of parameters given two different input sizes ? Here is a an example where the input is 440x340 and one with 550x425 and the first layer in each case has 9472 parameters. Thanks

```
_________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 440, 340, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad_Resnet50v2_classifica (None, 446, 346, 3)  0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_conv_Resnet50v2_classific (None, 220, 170, 64) 9472        conv1_pad_Resnet50v2_classificati
__________________________________________________________________________________________________


VS

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 550, 425, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad_Resnet50v2_classifica (None, 556, 431, 3)  0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_conv_Resnet50v2_classific (None, 275, 213, 64) 9472        conv1_pad_Resnet50v2_classificati
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: First layer is only input to the architecture. There is nothing to learn from the first Input layer. That is the reason you see "zero" params for first two layers. only the third layer has 9472 weights and biases to learn. As params (9472) depends on the filter size used in third layer, number of params doesn't depend on first layer.

Comment: @VishnuvardhanJanapati Thank you for your time. I'm asking about the first **convolution** layer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the first three layers as shown in your `model.summary`. Source code of `ResNet50` is [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/resnet50.py)

```
img_input = layers.Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
x = layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(3, 3), name='conv1_pad')(img_input)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (7, 7),strides=(2, 2),padding='valid',
                  kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                  name='conv1')(x)
```

Let us see how to estimate params in `Conv2D` layer.

> Kernel_width = 7, Kernel_height = 7, bias = 1
>
> Num_filters_in_prev_layer = 3
>
> Num_filters_in_current_layer =64

#### Formula:

Number of params = (Kernel_width*Kernel_height*Num_filters_in_prev_layer +bias)*Num_filters_in_current_layer

= (7*7*3+1)*64 = 9472

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why in my head I was stuck on the fact that the number of parameters depends on the input size, I see my mistake. Thanks for your answer and for pointing to the source code which I couldn't find.